# Android Fragments on lower API

Tags: android, api, android-fragments

well I'm starting to understand Android Fragments but this is still confusing for me. I need a little help. As it says android fragments is supported since API level 11 but you can download "support.v4" libraries pack for lower level APIs. Well first I create new project to try fragments on API level 15. Then I did the same with API level 8 and it does not work... I imported external jar and it sees all needed import as it should... What seems to be the problem here?

Here is my main class:

```
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class Fragment2Activity extends FragmentActivity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }
}
```

My main layout XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello" />

        <fragment 
   android:name="com.frag.Fragment2.frag"
   android:id="@+id/frag"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

My fragment class:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class frag extends Fragment {
       @Override
       public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
          // Inflate the layout for this fragment
          View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.hello_fragment, container, false);
          return v;
       }
    }
```

And my fragment layout XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    <TextView
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:text="THIS IS FRAGMENT"
   android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher"
/>

</LinearLayout>
```

**FIXED**

Comment: did you get this working?  I am having the same issue, what was your fix?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are still using the `android.view.fragment` class, which does not exist. You have to switch to `android.support.v4.app.fragment` on older devices.

Comment: it's actualy 'android.support.v4.app.Fragment' and I am using it ;/

Comment: Apparently not everywhere: `ClassNotFoundException: android.view.fragment`

Comment: This is my fragment class imports... ;/
  
 `import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;`

Comment: I tried changing `extends Activity` to `extends FragmentActivity` and import FragmentActivity class from support.v4 pack... still same...

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a lower API because of the minSdkVersion, you should know that you can use the latest sdk and set the minSdkVersion to a lower value. They have not to be the same.

Comment: If i do this i still can't run it on Android emulator 2.2 but i still can on 4.0.3 i changed at manifest ` <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="4"
          android:targetSdkVersion="15" />`

Answer (score 0):

OK so I had the same issue, and finally got it working.  First of all make sure you have the latest ADT tools.

1)Go into every activity that uses fragments and have them extend from `FragmentActivity` instead of `Activity`

2)if you haven't imported the support library into your build, then right-click on your project->Android Tools->Add Support Library

3)make sure in your xml the tags are `<fragment />` and not `<android.support.v4.app.fragment />`

hope that helps you out, took me a while to get it working.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, this issue is from ADT tools.

1. re-order the "Order and Export" in Java Build Path by
   src > gen > Private > other...
2. Add Support Library >> android-support-v4.jar