# does Android Annotations work on android verion 2.3?

Tags: android, dalvik

when I compile my app on android greater then 2.3 it works but on 2.3 it gives me this exception error

```
10-01 15:33:29.036: W/dalvikvm(4047): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x401c75a0)
10-01 15:33:29.046: E/AndroidRuntime(4047): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-01 15:33:29.046: E/AndroidRuntime(4047): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.pantera.ehotel/com.pantera.ehotel.MainActivity_}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #14: Error inflating class fragment
10-01 15:33:29.046: E/AndroidRuntime(4047):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1872)
10-01 15:33:29.046: E/AndroidRuntime(4047):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1893)
10-01 15:33:29.046: E/AndroidRuntime(4047):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:135)
10-01 15:33:29.046: E/AndroidRuntime(4047):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1054)
10-01 15:33:29.046: E/AndroidRuntime(4047):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-01 15:33:29.046: E/AndroidRuntime(4047):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:150)
10-01 15:33:29.046: E/AndroidRuntime(4047):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4389)
10-01 15:33:29.046: E/AndroidRuntime(4047):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-01 15:33:29.046: E/AndroidRuntime(4047):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
10-01 15:33:29.046: E/AndroidRuntime(4047):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:849)
10-01 15:33:29.046: E/AndroidRuntime(4047):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:607)
10-01 15:33:29.046: E/AndroidRuntime(4047):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-01 15:33:29.046: E/AndroidRuntime(4047): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #14: Error inflating class fragment
10-01 15:33:29.046: E/AndroidRuntime(4047):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:581)
10-01 15:33:29.046: E/AndroidRuntime(4047):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:623)
10-01 15:33:29.046: E/AndroidRuntime(4047):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:626)
10-01 15:33:29.046: E/AndroidRuntime(4047):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:408)
10-01 15:33:29.046: E/AndroidRuntime(4047):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
10-01 15:33:29.046: E/AndroidRuntime(4047):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276)
10-01 15:33:29.046: E/AndroidRuntime(4047):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:250)
10-01 15:33:29.046: E/AndroidRuntime(4047):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1712)
10-01 15:33:29.046: E/AndroidRuntime(4047):     at com.pantera.ehotel.MainActivity_.setContentView(MainActivity_.java:47)
10-01 15:33:29.046: E/AndroidRuntime(4047):     at com.pantera.ehotel.MainActivity_.onCreate(MainActivity_.java:38)
10-01 15:33:29.046: E/AndroidRuntime(4047):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1072)
10-01 15:33:29.046: E/AndroidRuntime(4047):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1836)
10-01 15:33:29.046: E/AndroidRuntime(4047):     ... 11 more
10-01 15:33:29.046: E/AndroidRuntime(4047): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.view.fragment in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.pantera.ehotel-2.apk]
10-01 15:33:29.046: E/AndroidRuntime(4047):     at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:240)
10-01 15:33:29.046: E/AndroidRuntime(4047):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:551)
10-01 15:33:29.046: E/AndroidRuntime(4047):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
10-01 15:33:29.046: E/AndroidRuntime(4047):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:471)
10-01 15:33:29.046: E/AndroidRuntime(4047):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:549)
10-01 15:33:29.046: E/AndroidRuntime(4047):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:66)
10-01 15:33:29.046: E/AndroidRuntime(4047):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:568)
10-01 15:33:29.046: E/AndroidRuntime(4047):     ... 22 more
```

I've looked everywhere but didn't find anything useful...

thanks in advance.... :-)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android Fragments on lower API](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10478798/android-fragments-on-lower-api)

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10478798/android-fragments-on-lower-api)

Comment: @Matteo Have you ever used android annotations?

Comment: No @Matteo this is not the issue here.... becasue the app works except on android version 2.3 or lower..

Comment: It seems you have a wrong class declared in the xml: `android.view.fragment`. I am pretty sure this class does not exist at all...

Comment: I solved the problem... I was not using support library v4 for fragments and in android 2.x there is no fragment class....!

Comment: @WonderCsabo can You tell me how to make a custom actionbar that works on 2.x also...?

Comment: Just do the same as you would without the support lib. The support lib completely implements the ActionBar from android 3.+.